# Sort on column and numerical value

Tags: bash

How do I sort based on the filename numerical value? (using OSX)

```
   1 file_1.txt
   7 file_3.txt
   1 file_111.txt
  11 file_7.txt
  14 file_15.txt
  54 file_10.txt
  54 file_20.txt
```

Desired output:

```
   1 file_1.txt
   7 file_3.txt
  11 file_7.txt
  54 file_10.txt
  14 file_15.txt
  54 file_20.txt
   1 file_111.txt
```

I tried sort -k 2,2 but it gives:

```
  1 file_1.txt
  54 file_10.txt
   1 file_111.txt
  14 file_15.txt
  54 file_20.txt
   7 file_3.txt
  11 file_7.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use "--version-sort" switch of sort:

```
sort -V -k 2,2
```